# Decoding an encoded URL

Tags: python, unicode, decode

I want to automatically download files from a pdf (in which there are links).
I already wrote a script which finds all these links and that works great, the problem I'm facing is with the files' names.
I want to save them by their default names so it will be easy to understand what each file is, without the need to manually change each name.
The problem is, each name is encoded using unicode (utf-8) according to this site https://www.webatic.com/url-convertor which converts the encoded strings great, but python doesn't let me use the function decode to decode this.

For example: this string %D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99+%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93 should become חומרי לימוד after decoding.

Answer (score 2):

Python has an URL parser:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.unquote_plus('%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99+%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93')
'חומרי לימוד'
```